# Angular: uncaught in promise error when using pipe and mergemap

Tags: angular, promise, pipe, subscribe

I am working with Angular 6, and I just found out about pipe and mergemap.

Basically, I am calling one service to read one of two different csv's (user chooses which one to read) from assets folder, get the date from each csv and use that date to select data from database, which will be used to create graphs.

So, what I did was

```
this.service.getCsv().pipe(
    mergeMap((data) => {
        let dtLst = getDate(data);
        return this.service.getDB(dtLst);
    })
).subscribe((result) => {
    switch(csvType) {
        // create first line graph
        // create another line graph
    }
})
```

Both csv's are turned into line graphs, and the first one works fine, but the second one throws **Uncaught (in promise)** error.

The error is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at Function.value (apexcharts.common.js:6)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:14)
    at t.create (apexcharts.common.js:6)
    at apexcharts.common.js:14
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:910)
    ...
```

I am using apexchart and the same template for both line graphs.

The thing is even though it throws that **Uncaught (in promise)** error, both graphs show up (in dev). It's not like a part is missing or not showing. It works as it's supposed to.

But, what I am worried about is if I publish, and it runs in prod, then it might crash or something else happens. So, before I publish, I want to fix this error, but I have no idea how to go about it.

I tried to catch error, but since the graphs show up, I don't think I can catch useful error logs.

Comment: What is the error? Which line throws it

Comment: @Antoniossss that's the thing. The error is not in my code. I updated my post.

Comment: Looks like something is missing in graph config or input data. Double chech apexcharts docs

Comment: @Antoniossss Okay, will do. Since the graph shows up, I doubt it is a big deal, but just to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

For future references,

I defined chartDataArray as undefined:

```
public chartDataArray;
```

and that threw Uncaught (in promise) error.

I just defined that variable as empty (empty array and empty strings), and the error disappeared.

```
public chartDataArray = {data: [], name: '', type: 'line'};
```